# Installing a ceiling fan remote

Tags: ceiling-fan

[image]I just bought a fan remote switch for my house.  Everything works fine.  My concern is the instructions state to remove the light switch controlling the fan light and wire nut the two white wires.  I only have white and black wires feeding the existing switch.  Is it OK to wire nut the black and white wires?  I think that will leave the fan always on and allow me to control it all from the remote.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?  Also, does this fan have a light kit on it?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I added the switch pic to the post.  Remote itself has no connections on it.  It is battery powered and just sits in the switch box.  Yes I have a light on the fan.

Answer (score 0):

### You have a switch loop, so go ahead and wirenut white and black together here

Your setup is a classical old-style *switch loop* wired using /2 cable.  One of the wires is the always hot and the other is the switched-hot -- there is no neutral here, even though one of the wires is white.  So, nutting them together will get you exactly what you want -- just don't forget to stick a black electrical tape flag on the white wire while you're at it!  (That's the standard way of marking a white wire as something other than a neutral.)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I followed your advice and everything is working.